# java webstart decompiler

Tags: java, decompiling

Is there anyway to decompile java webstart application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start the application, then fetch the JAR(s) from the webstart cache. Proceed to decompile like with any other Java application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. A Java Webstart application is just one form of deployment. The result is a bunch of jars copied to the users home directory. And these can of course be decompiled for example with [jad](http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the files with a .jar extension :)

Answer (score 0):

JNLPs are just regular text files interpreted by J2Plauncher. You can open it up in your favorite text editor and look for two things: `codebase` and `resources`.

Codebase is the base URL from which everything in `resources` is being downloaded. Meanwhile in resources, each jar field has a `href`. You can append that to base URL to download particular jar resource you need. Afterwards, regular jar decompilation process follows.